# Flash Player Ubuntu

Tags: maven, path, executable, flash, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to build my maven project on Ubuntu 12.04 and, it's complaining that java being not able to find flashplayer. However, I went through all the steps on the Adobe website to install flash player, and it's still complaining.

It also mentioned something about making sure flashplayer is available on PATH. However, I do not know where the path to this file is. There are several files that look like they could be the executable when I ran "locate flash" in the terminal.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you install `flashplugin-installer` you'll automatically get updates when Flash has security bugs. Which it does. Often. So often that you should not have to deal with Flash updates by hand. Incidentally, why does Maven or Java (`javac`? `java`?) even care about the Flash player?

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue for me and now it is working. The current project that I am working on is currently using Maven to build a Flash program which is why my Ubuntu 12.04 environment is complaining. Also, didn't Adobe stop support for Flash Player in Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't think Adobe ever _supported_ it -- all the updates in `/usr/share/doc/flashplugin-installer/changelog.gz` are from Ubuntu employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the *Flash Player 11.2 Projector* from http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html.

Unpack it to a folder, it should contain executable file *flashplayer*.

Add to path: `export PATH=$PATH:~/unpacked`.

Now maven should be able to use it.